# Partition list of numbers into groups that sum to specific sums

Tags: python, combinations, dynamic-programming, backtracking

I have a list of sums such as [7,6] and a list of numbers that will sum to the list of sums. For instance, [4,3,2,2,2]. Numbers in each list could be randomized. The goal is to return a result array such as [[4,3],[2,2,2]]. A backtracking solution takes a long time to run once the length of the list grows. Is there an efficient way to approach this problem? The current backtracking code looks like the following

```
def find_best_partition(numbers, targets):
best_partitions = []
best_difference = float('inf')

def partition_helper(numbers, targets, current_partitions, current_sums, current_index):
    nonlocal best_partitions, best_difference

    if current_index == len(numbers):
        difference = sum(numbers) - sum(current_sums)
        if difference < best_difference and set(current_sums).issubset(set(targets)):
            best_difference = difference
            best_partitions = [partition[:] for partition in current_partitions]
        return

    for i, target in enumerate(targets):
        if current_sums[i] + numbers[current_index] <= target:
            current_partitions[i].append(numbers[current_index])
            current_sums[i] += numbers[current_index]
            partition_helper(numbers, targets, current_partitions, current_sums, current_index + 1)
            current_partitions[i].pop()
            current_sums[i] -= numbers[current_index]

initial_partitions = [[] for _ in range(len(targets))]
initial_sums = [0] * len(targets)

partition_helper(numbers, targets, initial_partitions, initial_sums, 0)
return best_partitions
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Maybe better to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: And for inspiration, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudopolynomial_time_number_partitioning

Comment: My problem is not exactly the partition problem though. I know that the total sum of both lists will be the same, but the partition sums are different.

Comment: @GodIsOne I have added my current backtracking code